# c++ recursion causing segmentation faults (AND and OR queries with words)

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

My project makes me take parenthesized expressions of words and check the input files for where they occur. Such as
( Blue AND Black )
file1
( Dark AND ( Sky AND ( Flower OR Roses ) ) )
file2

etc

my program works when it comes to more simple expressions, like ( Blue OR Black )
but i run in segmentation faults when I perform more complex operations.

this is .cpp file that contains the errors
Im sure the error must occur in either doQuery or doMultipleQuery
(I didn't include includes and unimportant functions)

```
void WordSearch::doQuery(string query,string *result,int &size){
  int temp = 0, i = 0;

  MultiQuery thisQuery;
  thisQuery.parse_string(query);
  string word1 = thisQuery.getOperand1();
  string word2 = thisQuery.getOperand2();
  string op = thisQuery.getOperator();

  if (thisQuery.getSize(query) < 5) {
    List *list1;
    int index = 0, list1_size = 0;
    string temp[MAX_SIZE];  
    list1 = wordlist->search(word1);
    if (list1 != NULL){
      list1->all(temp, list1_size);
      while(index < list1_size){
        result[size] = temp[index];
        size++;
    index++;
      }

if(size == 0){
      result[size]="No Such File";
      size++;
    }

sort(result,result+size);
  }
  else
  cout<<"Wrong query";
return;
}

if (op=="AND") {
  size=0;
  and_operation(wordlist,word1,word2,size,result);
  sort(result,result+size);
} 
else if(op=="OR") {
  size=0;
  or_operation(wordlist,word1,word2,size,result);
  sort(result,result+size);
}
return;
} 


void WordSearch::doMultipleQuery(string query,string *result,int &size){
  MultiQuery thisQuery;
  thisQuery.parse_string(query);
  string operand1 = thisQuery.getOperand1();
  string operand2 = thisQuery.getOperand2();
  string oper = thisQuery.getOperator();
  int op1_size = thisQuery.getSize(operand1);
  int op2_size = thisQuery.getSize(operand2);
  string *temp1, *temp2;
  int index1 = 0, index2 = 0, size1 = 0, size2 = 0;

  if (thisQuery.getSize(query) <= 5) // ( Red AND Blue )
    doQuery(query, result, size);

  if (oper == "AND"){ // Files need to include both
    if (op1_size < 5 && op2_size >= 5){ // ( Pink OR ( Blue AND Black ) )
  string op1Temp = "( " + operand1 + " )";
      doQuery(op1Temp, temp1, size1);       
  doMultipleQuery(operand2, temp2, size2);
  while (index2 < size2) {
    while (index1 < size1){
      if (temp2[index2] == temp1[index1]){
    string tempString = temp2[index2];
    result[size] = tempString;
        size++;
      }
      index1++;
    }
      index2++;
      }
    }     
    if (op1_size >= 5 && op2_size < 5){ // ( ( Blue AND Black ) OR Pink )
  string op2Temp = "( " + operand2 + " )";
      doQuery(op2Temp, temp2, size2);   
  doMultipleQuery(operand1, temp1, size1);
  while (index1 < size1) {
    while (index2 < size2){
      if (temp1[index1] == temp2[index2]){
    string tempString = temp1[index1];
    result[size] = tempString;
    size++;
      }
      index2++;
    }
      index1++;
    }
  }   
  if (op1_size >= 5 && op2_size >= 5){ // ( ( Flower AND Red ) OR ( Pink AND Blue ) )
    doMultipleQuery(operand1, temp1, size1);
    doMultipleQuery(operand2, temp2, size2);
  while (index1 < size1) {
    while (index2 < size2){
      if (temp1[index1] == temp2[index2]){
    string tempString = temp1[index1];
    result[size] = tempString;
    size++;
      }
      index2++;
        }
        index1++;
  }
}  
}   

if (oper == "OR")   { // Files only need to include one
  if (op1_size < 5 && op2_size >= 5){ // ( Pink OR ( Blue AND Black ) )
  string op1Temp = "( " + operand1 + " )";
  doQuery(op1Temp, temp1, size1);
  doMultipleQuery(operand2, temp2, size1);
  while (index2 < size2){
result[size] = temp2[index2];
index2++;
size++;
  }
  while (index1 < size1){
result[size] = temp1[index1];
index1++;
size++;
  }
}   
if (op1_size >= 5 && op2_size < 5){ // ( ( Blue AND Black ) OR Pink )
  string op2Temp = "( " + operand2 + " )";
  doQuery(op2Temp, temp2, size2);   
  doMultipleQuery(operand1, temp1, size1);
  while (index2 < size2){
result[size] = temp2[index2];
index2++;
size++;
  }
  while (index1 < size1){
result[size] = temp1[index1];
index1++;
size++;
  }
}   
if (op1_size >= 5 && op2_size >= 5){ // ( ( Flower AND Red ) OR ( Pink AND Blue ) )
  doMultipleQuery(operand1, temp1, size1);
  doMultipleQuery(operand2, temp2, size2);
  while (index2 < size2){
result[size] = temp2[index2];
index2++;
size++;
  }
  while (index1 < size1){
result[size] = temp1[index1];
index1++;
size++;
  }
}
}   
sort(result,result+size);
}
```

Comment: Try to properly indent your code before posting here, It's hard to read code that isn't.

Comment: You might want to look into the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Also, segmentation faults mean you're doing the memory management wrong, which doesn't seem to be in the above code. How do you call `doQuery`, for example? (What is passed as `result`?)

Comment: Please visit http://sscce.org/. Copy pasting your code into a blank text file and compiling it will fail due to missing `#include`s and class definitions (namely `MultiQuery` and `WordSearch`.

Comment: The first thing you should do when you get a crash of any kind, segmentation fault included, is to run your program in a debugger. It will not only help you pinpoint the location of the crash, it will also let you examine variables to see what might have caused the crash.

Comment: Also, being a recursive algorithm, are you sure the stopping conditions works so it won't get a stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

There may be other errors as your code is very complex and convoluted, but one that sticks out is that you never allocate memory for the result arrays.
Look at `doMultipleQuery`:

```
string *temp1, *temp2;
int index1 = 0, index2 = 0, size1 = 0, size2 = 0;

if (thisQuery.getSize(query) <= 5) // ( Red AND Blue )
    doQuery(query, result, size);

if (oper == "AND"){ // Files need to include both
    if (op1_size < 5 && op2_size >= 5){ // ( Pink OR ( Blue AND Black ) )
        string op1Temp = "( " + operand1 + " )";
    doQuery(op1Temp, temp1, size1);   // <-- temp1 is uninitialized here       
doMultipleQuery(operand2, temp2, size2);  // <-- temp2 is uninitialized here
```

It would be better to use `std::vector` and `push_back` the results onto it.